# Why is == the standard equality operator?

Tags: conventions, code, programming

In all the programming languages I have ever used, the comparator for testing a mathematical equivalence is `==`. For example, in `python`:

```
if 7 == 8 - 1:
```

Why are all, as far as I am aware, programming languages designed like this? Wouldn't it make so much more sense to have only one `=` sign? I understand that `=` is used for defining and assigning variable values, as in

```
foo = bar
```

But surely the compiler can differentiate from an `if` statement (from the `if` tagged to the front of it) and a variable assignment (due to the *lack* of an `if` tagged to the front of it)? Is it a trend dating back to the `FORTRAN` days? Why hasn't it been changed?

Honestly, I can't see any logical reason to use `==` instead of `=`, when we surely have the computing power to use the `=` operator in two different ways rather than have two different operators. I'm sick of running into petty compiler errors - who thought of this stupid convention?

Comment: This wouldn't work in most C-like languages, because you can assign inside of a condition.

Comment: See also [In pseudo code what does := mean?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/101716/66652)

Comment: The premise of this question is quite fundamentally flawed. Pascal-based languages such as Pascal itself, Ada, Delphi, ..., all use a single `=` sign for equality comparison (whereas assignments are expressed by `:=`). And while the Pascal family might not currently be very fashionable and it is well possible to only work in C-based languages and Python, Pascal-based languages are probably nonetheless far from being "esoteric niche languages" in a way that one could say `==` is globally the "standard equality operator", or assuming that it applies to "all" programming languages,

Comment: GML, the scripting language used by [Game Maker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GameMaker:_Studio) actually permitted the use of `=` in both contexts in the way you're suggesting (sort of).  In my opinion, this was something of a disaster.  For example, the code `a = b = c` was perfectly valid, but you had to understand that this isn't multiple assignment (as most people thought it was), but really more equivalent to `a = b == c`.  Having one representation of two different operators is confusing.  I won't argue that using `=` for assignment is good, but having separate operators is.

Comment: In Visual Basic, there is no `==`.  The single `=` is used for assignment and comparison.

Comment: Note that in C and C++ (and other languages I'm sure) you can use `==` anywhere (not just in `if` statements).

Comment: @nhgrif: Well, in essentially all BASIC dialects and variants, VB.NET being by far the most respectable such at present.

Comment: I like eiffel's choices:  assignment `a := b` equality `a = b` non-equality `a /= b`

Comment: @chbaker0 Worse yet, you can also use `=` anywhere, including inside `if` statements.  Using the same symbol for both would eliminate a large group of common idioms.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the basic premise is wrong.

Comment: I knew Pascal and VB long before I learned C and both of them have no `==` operator

Comment: Having used IBM mainframe languages for many years, I struggle to think of any of those that use = and ==. Certainly not in PL/1 and Cobol. In PL/1 the key words are only keywords when used in the logical position for a keyword. So it is perfectly legitimate to have IF IF = THEN THEN THEN = ELSE ELSE = THEN; (assuming IF, THEN and ELSE were declared as variables). I still regularly forget to use == rather than = for comparison.

Comment: They could have chosen the word "sdfksd", but that's a bit harder to remember ;)

Comment: Because assign and test for equality are two different things.  Just as their and they're are two different words.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I have a feeling this question might be moved to the Stackoverflow site but Its an interesting question.

The reason behind this was because Fortran introduced the concept of using "=" as assigning values from one variable to another which led to a lot of confusion about what to use as an equality operator. To quote this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)#Assignment_versus_equality).

> The use of the equals sign = as an assignment operator has been
>   frequently criticized, due to the conflict with equals as comparison
>   for equality. This results both in confusion by novices in writing
>   code, and confusion even by experienced programmers in reading code.
>   The use of equals for assignment dates back to Heinz Rutishauser's
>   language Superplan, designed from 1949 to 1951, and was particularly
>   popularized by Fortran:
>
> *A notorious example for a bad idea was the choice of the equal sign to
>   denote assignment. It goes back to Fortran in 1957[a] and has blindly
>   been copied by armies of language designers. Why is it a bad idea?
>   Because it overthrows a century old tradition to let “=” denote a
>   comparison for equality, a predicate which is either true or false.
>   But Fortran made it to mean assignment, the enforcing of equality. In
>   this case, the operands are on unequal footing: The left operand (a
>   variable) is to be made equal to the right operand (an expression). x
>   = y does not mean the same thing as y = x.*
>
> —**Niklaus Wirth**, Good Ideas, Through the Looking Glass*

The history of how this led to == being used as the comparative operator is given below from [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_operator)

> Early FORTRAN (1956–57) was bounded by heavily restricted character
>   sets where "=" was the only relational operator available. There were
>   no "<" or ">" (and certainly no ≤ or ≥). This forced the designers to
>   define symbols such as .GT., .LT., .GE., .EQ. etc. and subsequently
>   made it tempting to use the remaining "=" character for copying,
>   despite the obvious incoherence with mathematical usage (X=X+1 should
>   be impossible).
>
> International Algebraic Language and ALGOL (1958 and 1960) therefore
>   introduced ":=" for assignment, leaving the standard "=" available for
>   equality, a convention followed by CPL, Algol W, BCPL, Simula, Algol
>   68, SETL, Pascal, Smalltalk, Modula2, Ada, Standard ML, OCaml, Eiffel,
>   Delphi, Oberon, Dylan, VHDL, and several other languages.
>
> On the other hand, the now very influential language C started off as
>   a minimal compiled language called B, which, in turn, started off as a
>   simplified version of BCPL (a typeless version of CPL). The intended
>   application for B was solely as a vehicle for a first port of (a then
>   very primitive) UNIX. In what has been described as a "strip-down"
>   process, **B replaced the original ":=" and "=" of BCPL by "=" and "=="**
>   respectively, the reason for this being unknown (and and or meanwhile
>   became "&" and "|", and later "&&" and "||", respectively). As a small
>   type system was later introduced, B became C. The popularity of C, and
>   its association with UNIX, led to Java, C#, and other languages
>   (including new versions of Fortran) following suit, syntactically,
>   despite this unnecessary conflict with the mathematical meaning of the
>   equal sign.

Comment: "B replaced the original ":=" and "=" of BCPL by "=" and "==" respectively, the reason for this being unknown" ... so ... we dont know? in any case, good answer, plenty of research. also, this can't be moved to stackoverflow.com - it is about language architecture, which isnt suited for SO, CR, Programmers, SF or SU, which leads me to here.

Comment: Here are a couple of quotes from Dennis Ritchie, the designer of C. "B ... is BCPL squeezed into 8K bytes of memory and filtered through [Ken] Thompson's brain." "Other flddles in the transition from BCPL to B were introduced as a matter of taste, and some remain controversial, for example the decision to use the single character = for assignment instead of :=." [Source: Dennis M. Ritchie: "The development of the C language", Sigplan Notices, Vol 28, #3, March 1993.]

Comment: One of Holt's design guidelines for programming languages is "usage shortens form". I.e. more frequently used constructs should have short expressions. So we can speculate that Thompson preferred a one character operator for the very common operation of assignment at the price of a two character operator for the less common operation of assignment. In Holt's own language TURING, the = is used for equals and the := for assignment; this is in keeping with another of Holt's guidelines, which is not to contradict cultural expectations. TURING's main users would be familiar with = from algebra.

Answer (score 5):

Checking equality is not used exclusively in `if` statements. For example:

`are_equal = foo == bar`

If the syntax would allow for using single equals sign, such assignment would be ambiguous:

`are_equal = foo = bar`

This could either mean "compare `foo` and `bar`, and assign the result to `are_equal`", or "assign `bar` value to both `are_equal` and `foo`".

Comment: There is an easy workaround to this problem: disallow fall-through assignment of the form `a=b=0`.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I wouldn't consider that an acceptable work-around, since it essentially disallows the assignment of generic Boolean expressions.  Sure, you could design the language in such a way that other operators could be allowed, like `a = b > 0`, but at that point I think the workaround stops being easy.  The real annoying part of it from a parsing perspective is now you have two different kinds of Boolean expressions: those that are in if statements (or other flow control structures) and those that are in assignments.

Comment: @Kyle Probably I wasn't clear enough; I was suggesting for `a = b = 0` to be parsed as `a = (b==0)`, not `a = 0; b = 0`. Double assignments are far less common.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Ahh, my mistake then.  I would consider that to be acceptable (barring just having two different operators).  But, yeah, multiple assignment is far less common (and I actually find them to be less readable, so I don't typically use them even if I can).

Comment: A more convincing example, maybe, is when passing the result of an equality test to a function. Indeed, I think use of both `f(a = b)` and `f(a == b)` is relatively common in C-like languages.

Comment: @JamesWood Of course, in C and C++ themselves, it's generally a bad idea to do that, since the order of operations isn't defined. Unlike for another C-class language, C#, where there is only one possible way to evaluate this (assign first, pass return value second).

Answer (score -3):

Why different operators, instead of letting the compiler figure it out?  I think perhaps some of you have been spoiled by multi-GHz processors with multiple GBytes of RAM.  Remember that C was designed in the 1970s, FORTRAN in the '50s, and consider the capabilities of the machines of the day.  If you want your compiles to finish within a practical amount if time, you don't give it complicated work to do.

As to why = for assignment, == for comparison, I'm just guessing but I think it might have something to do with patterns.  After all, you have a number of comparison operators, not just one.  E.g. C's ==, !=, >=, or FORTRAN's .eq., .ne., .gt..  == or .eq. fits into this pattern, leaving = free to be used for assignment.  (Besides, as has already been noted, one tends to write more assignments than equality comparisons, so a single-character assignment means a bit less typing.)

Comment: GW-BASIC was published in '83 and used `=` for both — I don't think "spoiled by multi-GHz processors" applies at all.

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy: But you need to remember that BASIC was never really intended for serious programming.  The name itself tells you that:  it's an acronym for "Beginner's All-purpose Symbolic Instruction Code".  Also, IIRC BASIC didn't use a plain = for assignment.  Rather, assignment was indicated by the LET keyword, e.g. "LET X = 1", so a simple parser could easily distinguish the two uses.

Comment: I said GW-BASIC for a reason, as neither of your counterarguments applies to it: it most certainly was intended and distributed for actual computing (however simplified for the masses) and that's what it was used for in practice (yes, even on fairly limited hardware with <<16 kB available), and GW-BASIC had already made LET optional.